# using equations in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, equation

I have a graph that looks like a block and I want to carve it into a circle. I have a dataframe with two columns, an xy scatter plot. I get an error for the variable 'eq = "(x-2.5)**2 + (y-2.5)**2"', but I thought I was following a guide elsewhere. Why does it not like the bolded line? Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('grid.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = [ 'x','y']

eq = "(x-2.5)**2 + (y-2.5)**2"
refined = df[ df.eval(eq)  = 4]

refined.to_csv('gridoutput.csv')
```

Comment: What's the error? (Also, you can't bold text within a code block.  I suggest you remove the excess characters so the code shown is exactly what you are executing.)

Comment: It appears you have an assignment `df.eval(eq) = 4`, where you want a equality condition `df.eval(eq) == 4`.  I'm not sure if this is your entire problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have 2 problems:

In the code, I believe you want to do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('grid.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['x','y'])

equation_x = 'Some transformation based on y' # f(y) = x
equation_y = 'Some transformation based on x' # f(x) = y

df['new_x'] = df.eval(equation_x)
df['new_y'] = df.eval(equation_y)

df.to_csv('gridoutput.csv')
```

The second problem is that you must be more specific, because you want to make a transformation for 'x' and one for 'y'. Also, the results have two solutions. Because for each point of 'y' you will find 2 possible 'x'.

You know you data better, then and you can find the exact tranformation for x and for y that that fit for you data.
In addition, maybe you will have to use a 'if' for cases lower or higher than x or y = 2.5 (the center of the circle).

Hope this helps.

Comment: So when I break the equation into two functions it still doesn't like the syntax of what I write: equation_x = '((x)-2.5)**2'. What about the syntax is wrong?